# IMPORTXML in Google Sheets syntax issue

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import

https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0

into a Google sheet and clean it up so their are three columns, one for `player id`, the next `name` and the next `team`.

I have input the formula into google sheets how I thought it should work but my syntax is wrong because I get the error

> Imported content is empty.

I am not targeting the right data and I'm not sure how to do it exactly here.

The formulas I am using are:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0","//span[@class='html-attribute-value']")
```

---

````
=IMPORTXML("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0","//span[@class='html-attribute-value']")```
````

---

````
=IMPORTXML("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0","//span[@class='html-attribute-value']")```
````

Here is my Google sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0Bt5z-Tky-tNhG_JtfE4FfjTRgQNRu_eQu2qVhQ-_E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY({
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0"),,1), "id=""(.+?)"""),
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0"),,1), "name=""(.+)")&" "&
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0"),,2), "(.+?)"""),
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=&SINCE=&PLAYERS=&JSON=0"),,2), "team=""(.+?)""")}, 
 "offset 3")))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ODgm7sWxLjmjHuHL62b2UDBBZP0Ydup2aJal2VBdmAo/edit#gid=1946353518)

Comment: Thanks so much for the example! How can I edit this to get both first and last name of the players? Right now it is only returning the last name.